# How to sum the divergent series $1+2+2+3+3+3+\cdots$ and $1+3+2+6+5+4+\cdots$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

In a different context, I encountered the divergent series $1+2+2+3+3+3+\cdots$, and I was wondering about its summation. Putting $f(x)=1+2x+2x^2+3x^3+3x^4+3x^5+\cdots$, we have $$(1-x)f(x)=1+x+x^3+x^6+\cdots=\frac12 x^{-1/8}\theta_2(0, \sqrt{x}).$$ This doesn't seem to help a lot, but made me wonder: Is there such a thing as "theta regularisation"?
And how to go about the original series?

A similar question concerns the "summing" of
$1+$
$3+2+$
$6+5+4+$
$10+\dots$

Comment: Just to understand - the first series: does it really mean $1+2 \cdot 2 + 3 \cdot 3 + ...$? Isn't that then only $\sum_{k=1}^\infty k^2 = \zeta(-2) $?

Comment: I would be happy if it were that easy. But I think this would be a forbidden applying of associativity. Like 1+(-1+1)+... "=" (1-1)+(1-1) ...

Comment: @Balarka: yes, actually I wanted to problematize that for any such infinite expression we need (at least) a valid indexing scheme; I feel it is not sufficient to trust the reader's imagination (and seriosity) that he can (and wants) to assume the same general rule. (A nice recollecting expression, btw, that term "Riemann's trap" - I like it  immediately!)

Comment: Both of these series diverge to $+\infty$.  Unless you have some *very* special application in mind, that is the only answer you need.